# Increase the 6-minute execution time limit of AppsScript

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a list of 8000 records and I am trying to analyze it using Google AppsScript.

It takes around 6-minutes to analyze only 1500 records, so I have to split my data into batches of 1500 records each and run the script multiple times.

Is there any way to increase the 6-minute execution time limit of Gppgle AppsScript?

Comment: Nope. It used to be that if you had a paid Google Workspace Account the execution time would be bumped up to 30 minutes but that no longer seems to be the case. Your only recourse is to optimize your code and/or employ a batch processing strategy.

Comment: I have a business account and I ran a script last night that took 8 minutes and it ran with no problems providing me with a directory tree of my entire directory thus allowing me to find a file I was having trouble finding.  So this seems inconsistent with previous comment and yet I think @TheAddonDepot is an intelligent user.

Comment: @Cooper You are correct, there are inconsistencies surrounding the limit for paid Google Workspace accounts. However, based on the quotas listed in the [reference documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas#current_limitations), 6 minutes seems to be the "official" limit. So that's what I go by.